# SSIS Package: Excel Destination

Tags: excel, ssis

I am trying to get a package to export the contents of a table to an excel spreadsheet. I set up the excel connection manager and create a new table or view.

When I try to create it it throws the error below:
'Country'is not a valid name.  Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long. (Microsoft JET Database Engine).

If I delete this entry it moves down the list with same error message.
Does anyone know how to resolve this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the exact error, are you dynamically creating the excel file is is it already created?

Comment: I think you can check Destination data length for this columns. Maybe they are shorter than in table.

Comment: I have the excel file created and when I go to create new table I get:

Comment: 'Columnname'is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long. (Microsoft JET Database Engine).

Answer (score 0):

Try to install this:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

after that make sure that your connection string properties has been changed to:

Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;

Extended Properties="EXCEL 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;"